# Path integral over fractal

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, fractals, winding-number

If a curve $C$ is a Koch curve (snowflake fractal) centered at origo, then is the following path integral defined?  $$\int_C \frac{1}{z}\space dz.$$

If it exists, the value must be $2\pi i$ for positively oriented curve $C$. This might be a silly question, but I haven't find clear reference. So under what condition we can say that the winding number exists, in an integral sense, for a continuous curve?

Comment: Typically, path integrals are only defined for rectifiable paths - most often, one only considers piecewise $C^1$ paths. But for analytic integrands, we can define path integrals for arbitrary paths. That doesn't have much practical value, however, there is rarely a good reason to look at paths that aren't piecewise $C^1$ in complex analysis.

Comment: @DanielFischer  But winding numbers for arbitrary continuous paths are of fundamental importance in topology?

Comment: In topology, yes. But in arbitrary topological spaces, you can't define the winding number via integrals, and when you're looking at nice spaces where you can define a winding number via integrals for a class of good curves (e.g. manifolds), you're interested in a) the integral definition gives the same result as the general topological definition and b) for every closed path, there is a good path homotopic to it. Then b) shows that it is sufficient to look at the "good" paths.

Answer (score 0):

The winding number is $2 \pi i$ as you say.  With regard to whether that symbol you've written is "formally meaningful," Caratheodory's Theorem says that if you take a conformal isomorphism $\phi$ between the disc and the interior of a Jordan region, then this extends to a homeomorphism on the boundary.

In particular, it gives a parametrization of the boundary by $\phi(e^{i \theta}) = \phi(\gamma(\theta)), \theta \in [0, 2\pi)$ which you can then formally jam under a one-dimensional Riemann integral depending solely on the Riemann-integrability of Re$(\phi(e^{i \theta}))$ and Im$(\phi(e^{i \theta}))$.  So instead of writing what you've written (which really isn't correct; I'd be shocked to hear that when you first defined a path integral, you didn't do so for piecewise-differentiable curves only), you should write $$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\phi(\gamma(\theta))} \gamma'(\theta) d\theta$$

which does have a totally unambiguous meaning, assuming integrability.  With regard to a comment made earlier, paths worse than $\mathcal{C}^1$ are plenty interesting - unless the Dirichlet Problem is uninteresting.